# Cos'è il "cofano della cova"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> Mia sorella Pina è molto più grande di me. Io piccolino, lei amava cucirmi i vestiti e scrivere il mio nome, quando metteva la chioccia, su un uovo, per farmi nascere un bel pulcino. La ricordo sorridente accanto al **cofano della cova** coperto dal crivello da cui usciva qualche filo di paglia e il sospiro della gallina.

Ho cercato il termine "cofano" in alcuni dizionari, ma non capisco cos'è questo "cofano della cova" di cui parla il testo. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il ***cofano della cova*** è un modo per descrivere il luogo del pollaio dove la chioccia (cioè la gallina che cova e alleva pulcini) può appunto covare le uova in attesa della loro schiusa.

*[Còfano](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cofano/)* qui ha il significato latino di *cophĭnus* «cesta»:

> 2. ant. o region. Paniere, cesto.

Esso è descritto come coperto dal [crivello](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/crivello/) (cioè una sorta di vaglio, griglia) posto a protezione e costituiva una sorta di antenato contadino delle attuali incubatrici.